# Which (if any) Stack Exchange site to choose for questions about A/B or multivariate testing?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a particular Stack Exchange site that would be appropriate for a question about A/B testing? I thought ux.stackexchange.com would be a place to start, but tag volume for these terms is small to nonexistent.

Thanks - bonus is if someone could recommend an existing community for this topic failing the existence of a Stack Exchange community.

Comment: What specifically are you looking for help on?  What aspect of A/B testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For help on using A/B testing to test UX, yes, I would suggest asking on ux.stackexchange.com.  Don't read too much into tag volume.  Rather than assuming you're not going to get a good answer, how about trying to ask the question and seeing if you get a good ansewr or not?

For help on statistical analysis of data from A/B tests, maybe stats.stackexchange.com.

Do read the help center and faqs on those sites before posting.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of stats. :)